# Prevent User to remove software

Tags: 14.04, users

How can I make Users without any Administrative privileges?

I have installed Ubuntu 14.0.4 for the students to learn Ubuntu.

Guest user is best but user can not save program files or anything inside it..
please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the user from the `sudo` group:

```
sudo deluser <username> sudo
```

This way the user will be unable to run any `sudo` command.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to create a permanent guest account and give it write access to a home folder.

Here are detailed instructions on how to do that: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession You can skip past the "Hooks facilitate customization" section, and you can replace the name `guest-prefs` with `students` or whatever you like.

Comment: Or just create a user with no administrative privileges.